# Слово "русалка"

Tags: этимология

Почему водяная нечисть называется "русалка"? Здесь подразумевается, что русалки водятся только у русских, или цвет их волос - русый?)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, ни то ни другое.
Производное от русалия - праздник весны. От греческого или латинского слова с тем же значением. В основе латинского первоисточника - корень "роза", исходно - "праздник роз".

Кстати, для полного понимания надо иметь в виду, что русалка первоначально - существо наземное, лесное. Птица с головой девушки. Почему и сидит у Пушкина на ветвях.